# A mother takes her children to a buffalo farm

Tags: identify-this-movie

This movie <s>was from around</s> I saw in 2004 or 2005 (English/Hollywood).

There was a main protagonist, although I can't remember what he looked like.

But there was this other lady (single parent) she had a kid (or two). She toke him/them to a farm, where it is kind of a zoo but only buffaloes are there to see. It was not a fancy place for tourists.

When they arrived, they were the only customers or visitors there. 
A man had opened the door for them and he explained that there is a fee for entrance. The lady did not have any money (or maybe she couldn't afford to spend money on a zoo), so she started to apologies to her children.

The man who opened the gate for them overheard her apologizing to her children, and said something like "But today is Monday, so it is free of charge".

The movie is not about the zoo, and not about the man who let them in without money. But this scene stuck to my memory and I really admired how it was written.

Comment: I think I remember this movie. The single mother and kids were on a bit of a road trip. It wasn't a zoo but a fairly sad kind of "wild west" museum  / show on a remote stretch of highway if I recall correctly. Sorry, I can't remember the name!

Comment: @NeilRobertson that's right! It was a sad place and the mother with kids were traveling. Too bad you can't remember the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens in "[Radio Flyer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105211/?ref_=nv_sr_1)" from 1992. From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Flyer_%28film%29):

> Mike (Tom Hanks) is observing his two sons fighting; with one insisting that a promise doesn't mean anything. To make them understand that a promise does mean something, he tells them the story of his youth. Young Mike (Elijah Wood), his little brother Bobby (Joseph Mazzello), their mother Mary (Lorraine Bracco) and their German Shepherd Shane move to a new town after their father/husband leaves them. There, Mary marries a new man named Jack (Adam Baldwin), who likes the others to call him "The King". Unbeknownst to Mary, the King is an alcoholic who often gets drunk and beats Bobby.
>
> The two boys, seeing that their mother has found happiness at last with the King, are reluctant to tell either her or the police about the abuse. They instead try to avoid the King by exploring and having adventures amidst the turmoil and traumatic experiences. In the process, the two devise a plan for Bobby to escape the King once and for all.

At some point, the mom and her 2 kids come across an 'old west' exhibit which is really just a buffalo in a pen, and the exact scene you're describing unfolds. Here's the trailer:

Comment: Link only answers are not considered "good answers." And your link does not prove anything. Also, the OP says the movie was from around 2004 or 2005, **not 1992.**

Comment: Pretty sure they *are* right, though, so I added some stuff.

Comment: @MeatTrademark I have edited my question to point out my mistake. I saw the movie in 2005, but I couldn't tell if it was released in the same year or before (which was the case). Thanks

Comment: Hey, stick around. You'll get even better.  We were all new here are some point. And we all get better. No worries. You seem like someone who will be a valuable member. I'm glad you found your answer.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).